# Upgrading to CI 3.0.1

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am busy upgrading my CodeIgniter from 2.1.4 to 3.0.1, and following the instructions here: `http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html`

Since I started that, I get this error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND `password` = ?' at line 3
```

Here is the complete query:

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM `icms4_user`
        WHERE `username` = ?
        AND `password` = ?
    ";
```

It appears as if the upgrade now causes the database class to refuse to replace the question mark placeholders with their appropriate values.

Query code looks like this:

`$q = $this->db->query($sql, array($user, $pass));`

Anyone has any idea about what could cause this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to make the query?

Comment: `$q = $this->db->query($sql, array($user, $pass));` - will update the question too. Thanks.

Comment: Try with `array('{$user}', '{$pass}')` or `array(\'{$user}\', \'{$pass}\')`.

Comment: Tried that Tpojka, not solving the problem. There are many of these queries, and they all worked before I did the upgrade. The variables are properly set. Currently investigating reverting the upgrade via Git and restart it. I am clueless about what is going on.

Comment: I just download a clean CI301 and make the same code as you show, no problem at all. With a wrong table name it shows the SQL with the ? replaced with the values. I didn't split the $sql into multiple line, will there be chance there's some strange characters there?

Comment: Downloading a clean install will not replicate my problem. I also made a clean install and it works. The upgrade process is causing issues for me. Just not sure where and what is happening. All was working fine before I start the upgrade. No strange characters as you think there may be. They say don't fix if it is not broken, but in this case, security and sessions upgrade was a must...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some changes in my config.php file, the problem went away. I have (silly me) used db_prefix in my config.php as opposed to my database.php file, and configured that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For example I have just created a test user controller and a test function for database info and notice I have got `" . '?' . "` currently I have just put email instead of password just for example only

**Var dump to show working**

```
array(4) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["user_group_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["username"]=> string(4) "demo" ["email"]=> string(13) "demo@demo.com" } 2
```

Controller Example

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    // Example Only

    // hard code in just for testing
    $username = 'demo';
    $email = 'demo@demo.com';

    $user_info = $this->test($username, $email);

    var_dump($user_info);

    // Echo Test Data
    echo $user_info['user_id'];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $user_info['user_group_id'];
    echo '</br>';
    echo $user_info['username'];
}

public function test($username, $email) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user 
        WHERE username = " . '?' . "
        AND email = " . '?' . "
    ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($username, $email));

    return $query->row_array();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: That did not solve it for me. Thanks for your comment though. I continued tinkering, and it started working after I made a change in my config.php file.